# Simple histogram generation of integer data in C#

Tags: c#, histogram

As part of a test bench I'm building, I'm looking for a simple class to calculate a histogram of integer values (number of iterations taken for an algorithm to solve a problem). The answer should be called something like this:

```
Histogram my_hist = new Histogram();

for( uint i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_RESULTS; i++ )
{

    myHist.AddValue( some_result );
}

for( uint j = 0; j < myHist.NumOfBins; j++ )
{
     Console.WriteLine( "{0} occurred {1} times", myHist.BinValues[j], myHist.BinCounts[j] );
}
```

I was suprised a bit of googling didn't turn up a neat solution but maybe I didn't search for the right things. Is there a generic solution out there or is it worth rolling my own?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use SortedDictionary

```
uint[] items = new uint[] {5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 2}; // sample data
SortedDictionary<uint, int> histogram = new SortedDictionary<uint, int>();
foreach (uint item in items) {
    if (histogram.ContainsKey(item)) {
        histogram[item]++;
    } else {
        histogram[item] = 1;
    }
}
foreach (KeyValuePair<uint, int> pair in histogram) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} occurred {1} times", pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

This will leave out empty bins, though

Comment: +1: That looks like a good start. As it happens I'm only interested in bins which contain data :-)

Comment: Adding items one by one to a `SortedDictionary` is significantly slower than using a normal dictionary and sorting the list of `KeyValuePair<,>` elements at the end. 
Inserting and retrieving elements in a `SortedDictionary` are both **O(log(N))**. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=net-5.0#remarks  - see my answer below for a faster code sample.

Answer (score 6):

Based on BastardSaint's suggestion I came up with a neat and fairly generic wrapper:

```
public class Histogram<TVal> : SortedDictionary<TVal, uint>
{
    public void IncrementCount(TVal binToIncrement)
    {
        if (ContainsKey(binToIncrement))
        {
            this[binToIncrement]++;
        }
        else
        {
            Add(binToIncrement, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

So now I can do:

```
const uint numOfInputDataPoints = 5;
Histogram<uint> hist = new Histogram<uint>();

// Fill the histogram with data
for (uint i = 0; i < numOfInputDataPoints; i++)
{
    // Grab a result from my algorithm
    uint numOfIterationsForSolution = MyAlorithm.Run();

    // Add the number to the histogram
    hist.IncrementCount( numOfIterationsForSolution );
}

// Report the results
foreach (KeyValuePair<uint, uint> histEntry in hist.AsEnumerable())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} occurred {1} times", histEntry.Key, histEntry.Value);
}
```

Took me a while to work out how to make it generic (to begin with I just overrode the `SortedDictionary` constructor which meant you could only use it for `uint` keys).

Comment: BastardSaint's method of checking using Contains() is somewhat (a lot) wiser than relying on exceptions. This will give a spike everytime a new number's frequency is getting stored.

Comment: Thinking about it now, perhaps doing the check every time is a better way of checking for existance. I guess it depends whether you're expecting to add lots of very similar items (which I am) or whether you're expecting a histogram with many more unique entires. My hunch was that it would be faster in my case(?)

Comment: Changed the example to use the if-else solution.

Comment: Can you think of a good way to extend this approach to handle bins larger than 1?

Comment: You could specify the keys as String^ values and then add a key like "0-10" ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use Linq:

```
var items = new[] {5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 2};
items
    .GroupBy(i => i)
    .Select(g => new {
        Item = g.Key,
        Count = g.Count()
    })
    .OrderBy(g => g.Item)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(g => {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} occurred {1} times", g.Item, g.Count);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

This builds on the accepted answer. The problem is that building a `SortedDictionary` iteratively is slooow, because both insertions *and* retrievals cost **O(log(N))**.

That can be avoided if you don't need to display the histogram as it is accumulating.

My modification uses a normal `Dictionary` and only sorts it at the end into a `SortedList`.

For a sample size of 10M items, this version is about 11x faster (on my machine), at the cost of slightly higher memory usage until the GC kicks in (~10% extra memory).

```
//generate a random sample
Random r = new Random();
var items = Enumerable
    .Range(1, 10_000_000)
    .Select( _ => (uint)r.Next(100_000))
    .ToList();

//build the histogram using a normal dictionary with O(1) lookups and insertions.
var tempHistogram = new Dictionary<uint, int>();
foreach (uint item in items)
{
    if (tempHistogram.ContainsKey(item))
    {
        tempHistogram[item]++;
    }
    else
    {
        tempHistogram[item] = 1;
    }
}

//Sort it once. SortedList conveniently has a ctor that takes a dictionary.
var sortedHistogram = new SortedList<uint, int>(tempHistogram);

foreach (KeyValuePair<uint, int> pair in sortedHistogram.Take(100))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} occurred {1} times", pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

For really large samples (larger than the available memory) there are amazing probabilistic algorithms that solve this problem.
They are also quite good for *streaming* data.
Look for 'quantile sketches'. Here's an implementation from the Apache foundation: https://datasketches.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

My implementation of a simple extension method to create a histogram:

```
public static IReadOnlyDictionary<T, int> ToHistogram<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
   => enumerable.GroupBy(item => item).ToDictionary(grouping => grouping.Key, grouping => grouping.Count());
```