# Is there any way to access histogram in excel using visual c#?

Tags: c#

I just created, opened and saved data to an excel file. But i want to draw histogram using the data in excel with the help of c#.Anyone please suggest me a way to do this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried?  A [Google](http://www.google.com) search found me this... [histogram C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926067/simple-histogram-generation-of-integer-data-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Have you searched? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926067/simple-histogram-generation-of-integer-data-in-c-sharp

Comment: Welcome to the site Prudhvi. What have you tried? There are multiple parts to solving this problem. Getting the data from excel into memory, how to represent it in memory and how to display it. Also, what is the end result required? Why not just draw a graph in excel?

Comment: http://trompelecode.com/blog/2012/04/how-to-create-an-image-histogram-using-csharp-and-wpf/

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/trevormisfeldt/Histogram08302005002754AM/Histogram.aspx  for download of code

Comment: yeah i searched but i found code for drawing surface chart but not a histogram. My actual problem is histogram is to be created with data analysis option in excel and the histogram should be saved in excel file.